# Proving inequality relation between two complex numbers and a positive real parameter.

Tags: inequality, reference-request, complex-numbers, soft-question

**Question:**

> Prove that: $$|z_1+z_2|^2 \le (1+c)|z_1|^2+(1+{1\over c})|z_2|^2$$
> where $z_1,z_2$ are complex numbers and $c$ is a positive real parameter.

**Solution:**

> We can write $$|z|^2=z\bar z$$
> Same way $$(z_1+z_2)(\bar z_1+\bar z_2) \le (1+c)(z_1)(\bar z_1)+(1+{1\over c})(z_2)(\bar z_2)$$
> which will yield $$z_2\bar z_1+z_1\bar z_2 \le cz_1\bar z_1+{1\over c}z_2\bar z_2$$

How to solve after this? Is this question correct? Am I doing correct?

**Post script: Offtopic**

> This maybe irrelevant with the question. If you want to answer it you may or you may not.
>
> As I'm quite new to the topic. Can anyone of you suggest a good book for a beginner as there is nothing left in the book I'm reading. It's just introduction with few problems. This is the last one.
>
> How to pronounce $\bar z$? Some pronounce z bar and some strictly prohibit saying the same. They rather say complex conjugate of z.

Thanks for answering any of these questions or providing any hints.

Comment: @MartinR- Thanks.